# Can we predict Dextrorotatory and levorotatory character of an organic molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, optical-properties

Can we predict in which direction a given molecule will bend plane polarized light?

If I have a molecule with R form in R-S nomenclature does it mean that the molecule will be dextrorotatory or is it to be found by experiments like finding out rate of a reaction by experiments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple set of rules that one can use to determine the absolute configuration from the specific rotation, or the other way around.

A quick web search did dig up [this reference](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0957-4166%2800%2900178-6) that deals with calculating the specific rotation for arbitrary molecules, but it requires some fairly sophisticated algorithms. In principle, you could reproduce their methods, but it would require a substantial time commitment unless you are familiar with the software they describe. (Which is [Gaussian](http://www.gaussian.com/), if you're interested.)

Comment: +1, there are no simple ways of doing this. [Electronic structure calculations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chemistry_computer_programs) can yield this information, as in the paper you link to, but this is research-level chemistry requiring powerful computers…